# Can I have 2 recovery phone numbers in my Google account?

Tags: google-account

When I travel abroad, it often happens that my original carrier is not valid, which means that sometimes I have to change my phone number to another carrier when I am in another country. So effectively I have two phone numbers.

Is there a way to use two recovery phone numbers in Google?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, you can.

1. Go to [your account](https://myaccount.google.com/)
2. Under *Security* (was *Sign-in & security*), go to **Signing in to Google**
3. Go to **2-Step Verification**
4. Under *Backup options for when your primary is unavailable*
5. Click **Add a phone number**

To use it, when you login, click **Try another way to sign in** under the code box. You will be presented with a list of options where you will find the second phone number as one of them.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this second phone won't receive [security alerts](https://security.google.com/settings/security/alerts). (A shortcoming on Google's part, not in the answer per-se)

Comment: I am on the "Signing in to Google" page and I don't see "2-Step Verification" anywhere. And the "Recovery phone" only lets me have 1 number, not two.

Comment: Dai is right. You can only see your last number. But when you change the current recovery phone, I was still able to see past options when I perform the 2-step verification. Not sure if this is a bug or a feature, I thought it would be worth mentioning.

Comment: That is for adding a second phone for Two Step Verification, not an account recovery phone, of those you can only have one and one email,

Comment: 2023-02-22 There no longer appears the option "2-step verification", and there is no way to directly add a second verification number.  A serious data-loss hazard.  Apple and Microsoft do it way better.  Can't even use a TOTP app for MFA on Google accounts.

Comment: I wanted to answer, but 100 bonus rep isn't enough.  The answer, as of today (2023-02-22), is almost assuredly "NO, you can't."  And I have the screen shots to prove it.  You'll just have to confirm it yourself.  Tested with a personal account, and with a Google Workspace admin account.

Comment: I just tried this as well and I believe @BISI is correct. No way to add a 2nd verification email or phone number that I can tell.